# Sort/filter a datatable by a column which is not included in the entity

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a datatable which has columns defined in my entity. I also added another column named `total` in index.xhtml:

```
...
<p:column headerText="total">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.total}" />
</p:column>
...
```

This column calculates and returns the sum of columns in each row. Everything works fine except when I want to sort/filter by columns, the `total` column remains untouched.

I guess I should add the `total` field in my entity too, but it doesn't seem practical.
Does primefaces has a better and more straight solution for such situations?

Comment: Adding it to your entity sounds trivial - why do you say not practical?

Comment: @Romski imagine I use this entity in many pages. in addition to the _total_ field, I'm going to have 5 or 6 more fields which are specific to one page, another 3 fields which are specific to another page and so on. all these fields can be calculated from entity fields. so is it yet practical to add all these fields to the entity? I don't think so.

Comment: Can you post some screen shot ?

Comment: @CanisMajoris Did you see [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf)? Maybe updating table columns can be helpful.

Comment: @CanisMajoris - go with the wrapper class then. Make a wrapper class for your entity, and add these utility methods. But beware of the "Voltron entity". If its being used in several places for several reasons, maybe its actually several different entities bound together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want the entity class to remain immutable, I can think of two solutions for the matter:

1) Create a subclass of your entity, but do not declare it as an entity. You can also create a wrapper class receiving `Entity` as a constructor parameter, and directly manipulating the data on the original object via getters and setters. Subclassing has the advantage of inheriting the public methods already, but the disadvantage of having to care for the data.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6422622/1532705) on why not to subclass an entity as an entity and the persistance issues.

```
public class EntitySubclass extends Entity {

    private Entity parent;

    public EntitySubclass(Entity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        // set all data from parent to this entity.
    }

    // fetch the parent object for persistance.
    public Entity getParent() {
        // set all data from this to parent.
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        int iDidMathOnEntityData = 0;
        // do math
        return iDidMathOnEntityData;
    }

}
```

jsf:

```
<p:column headerText="total">
    <h:outputText value="#{subClass.total}" />
</p:column>
```

---

2) Use the `rowIndexVar` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5704087/1532705) and call a method on the Managed Bean passing the `rowIndexVar` as parameter. Then fetch the corresponding entity and do the math. [Requires EL 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8326551/1532705).

```
<p:column headerText="total">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.total(rowIndexVar)}" />
</p:column>
```

managed bean:

```
public int total(int rowIndexVar) {
    int iDidMathOnEntityData = 0;
    Entity e = getEntityByIndex(rowIndexVar);
    // do some math
    return iDidMathOnEntityData;
}
```

---

3) if someone with the same issue has no problem with editting the entity, you can add the `getTotal()` method as `@Transient`:

```
    @Transient
    public int getTotal() {
        int iDidMathOnEntityData = 0;
        // do math
        return iDidMathOnEntityData;
    }
```